# Filter columns by dashboard multi-select parameter

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to render a time series, but I have too many columns to show by default. To remedy this I figured I would present the user with a multi-select of all the columns and downselect the columns I render to that list, but I can't for the life of me figure out or find an answer on how to do it.

I have data with, say, columns Time, X1, X2, ... X120 and a multi-select parameter _columns of that table | getschema | project ColumnName | where ColumnName != "Time". I want to project to Time and the contents of _columns.

I can only find how to filter rows based on some column's value vs the multi-select. I feel like I'm missing something very simple.

Comment: How many rows? Is there a fixed time interval between rows? Is it raw data or result of an aggregation?

Comment: More than enough that dashboard doesn't want to graph them all at once, so more than a hundred. It's telemetry data, fixed time interval; in this case each column is in the same unit like degrees Fahrenheit, just from a different device or location. I guess it's raw technically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution supports multi-selection.

The original data looks something like that:

[image: Data]

```
// Data sample generation. Not part of the solution.
let p_start_time = startofday(ago(1d));
let p_interval = 5m;
let p_rows = 15;
let p_cols = 120;
let data = materialize
(
    range Timestamp from p_start_time to p_start_time + p_rows * p_interval step p_interval
    | mv-expand MetricID = range(1, p_cols) to typeof(int)
    | extend MetricVal = rand(), MetricName = strcat("x", tostring(MetricID))
    | evaluate pivot(MetricName, take_any(MetricVal), Timestamp)
    | project-reorder Timestamp, * granny-asc 
 );
// Solution starts here
// We assume the creation of a parameter named _MetricName, in the dashboard
// Uncomment the following line when executed outside the context of the dashboard
let ['_series'] = dynamic(['x1', 'x3', 'x7', 'x100', 'x120']);
data
| project Timestamp, pa = pack_all()
| project Timestamp, cols = bag_remove_keys(pa, set_difference(bag_keys(pa), _series))
| evaluate bag_unpack(cols)
| render timechart
```

| Timestamp | x1 | x100 | x120 | x3 | x7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-20T00:00:00Z | 0.40517703772298719 | 0.86952520047109094 | 0.67458442932790974 | 0.20662741864260561 | 0.19230161743580523 |
| 2022-10-20T00:05:00Z | 0.098438188653858671 | 0.14095230636982198 | 0.10269711129443576 | 0.99361020447683746 | 0.093624077251808144 |
| 2022-10-20T00:10:00Z | 0.3779198279036311 | 0.095647188329308852 | 0.38967218915903867 | 0.62601873006422182 | 0.18486009896828509 |
| 2022-10-20T00:15:00Z | 0.141551736845493 | 0.64623737123678782 |  |  |  |

... etc.

[image: Dashboard]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA21SPW/bMBDd/SsOWUS1cm2nCDoU2bJ0aJZ%20DUEgXMiTzJoiBZJypKI/vkdalh2gGijwvt7ju7fZwANGhIBdbwhasuQxamc/wKOL0KOP4BqIe4LgzJAzK0OcqUPkZB11R3AP%20eIahZPA1omdKsvPc522kfwRDVfddeegd6%20BA7u7c0A6kwO321NEJVb30CE3azT6D63ECvjzaFuC7wzLmF0PjXfdWzbRvb2/P%20O9u2YTIvVX9zz7L3THNY09WgVfKXotvzwwiQwpdtVMs0wIcerJNYLby7mVxkhL38/8Xm5Uoqzm2CPOUnmJUdyMNxUP4pu2rTijlcs05jTw46HXRxfFZQI34YFqtJNYoBhiEeQ8oPfuN8m49uS8In8pqFiHlpnZaY1Bwgp4U5sNfJvXe1plgD15SvFfBBjCkHRlE0hP2R7JFJjswYxYQLD8V1Bf09Q2dygM%20xeHXqVhP6x0XUc25lTjjHGv/Hww2hK87smyiiSHyLPcEINWM6rjLY2LEy8jk1OeijqwRygUz6yumpiKluKpGHdFBcX4MZ%20f8rnbbk//223xzM9OJlstUl1L1Cfz9SgPNRojyv8XzZ59wbb21Lkj1QeaguixgkCxVrppWEQrSaSSOce7mvmWaeyy51Qy2AQpssk4x71pc8nEcs9L%20QdwE%20KurQMAAA==)

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked. I apologize that it took so long to get here.

Comment: It was an interesting ride though :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**

There is also a simple solution for data that looks something like that:

[image: Series]

This kind of data might be created by a make-series operator with multiple aggregation functions, e.g. -

```
make-series series_001 = count(), series_002 = min(x), series_003 = sum(x), series_004 = avg(x), series_005 = countif(type == 1), series_006  = countif(subtype == 123) on Timestamp from ago(7d) to now() step 1d
```

```
// Data sample generation, including series creation.
// Not part of the solution.
let p_series_num = 100;
let data = materialize
(
    range i from 1 to p_series_num step 1 
    | project series_name = strcat("series_", substring(strcat("00", i), -3))
    | mv-apply range(1, 7, 1) on (summarize make_list(rand()))
    | evaluate pivot(series_name, take_any(list_))
    | extend Timestamp = range(now() - 6d, now(), 1d)
    | project-reorder Timestamp, * granny-asc 
);
// Solution starts here
// We assume the creation of a parameter named _series, in the dashboard
// Uncomment the following line when executed outside the context of the dashboard
let ['_series'] = 'series_001'; 
data
| project Timestamp, column_ifexists(['_series'], real(null))
| render timechart
```

| Timestamp | series_001 |
| --- | --- |
| ["2022-10-08T15:59:51.4634127Z","2022-10-09T15:59:51.4634127Z","2022-10-10T15:59:51.4634127Z","2022-10-11T15:59:51.4634127Z","2022-10-12T15:59:51.4634127Z","2022-10-13T15:59:51.4634127Z","2022-10-14T15:59:51.4634127Z"] | ["0.35039128090096505","0.79027849410190631","0.023939659111657484","0.14207071795033441","0.91242141133745414","0.33016368441829869","0.50674771943297525"] |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=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)

Comment: Thanks, this is extensive.
My data is in the "usual" single timestamp per row form, is there an easy way to collapse it into the form you start with? I can't seem to find a quick way to do that either.

Comment: See updated answer. I realized there is a much simpler solution which also covers your case.

Answer (score 0):

It might be very simple, if our tabular data (post creation of the series) looks something like that:

[image: Series]

This kind of data might be created by a *make-series* operator with *by* clause, e.g. -

`make-series count() on Timestamp from ago(7d) to now() step 1d by series_name`

In that case, all we need to do is add a filter on the series name, E.g. -

```
// Data sample generation, including series creation.
// Not part of the solution.
let p_series_num = 100;
let data = materialize
(
    range i from 1 to 1000000 step 1 
    | extend Timestamp = ago(rand()*7d) 
            ,series_name = strcat("series_", substring(strcat("00", tostring(toint(rand(p_series_num)))), -3))
    | make-series count() on Timestamp from ago(7d) to now() step 1d by series_name
);
// Solution starts here
// We assume the creation of a parameter named _series, in the dashboard
// Uncomment the following line when executed outside the context of the dashboard
let ['_series'] = 'series_001'; 
data
| where series_name == _series
| render timechart
```

| series_name | count_ | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| series_001 | [1434,1439,1430,1428,1422,1372,1475] | ["2022-10-07T15:54:57.3677580Z","2022-10-08T15:54:57.3677580Z","2022-10-09T15:54:57.3677580Z","2022-10-10T15:54:57.3677580Z","2022-10-11T15:54:57.3677580Z","2022-10-12T15:54:57.3677580Z","2022-10-13T15:54:57.3677580Z"] |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA1VSPW/bMBDdBeg/PGSxVDi1jA4dDG+dsyRBhyIIaPFsERV5BnmC2yI/PkeJAtwb790d3wd3O/wwYpCMv46ECwWKRhyHLVzox8m6cEGi6CihjzRDX+tqt8MTC64mCvgMGQiJx6mgIyn0vmy9h8njiH3XHRbA5ueO8EYUN6P7R3XV1BW0ogkXgsM5sscewnktF5LQVTvL2Afoj1CweHGekihzvWcu3Oi+bdov321bJtfarlyMJ51NEnsjzUPpPmyRppM2VWuzYl2nbeHSFXZBlvv3wlqtLR6/te3KzJvf9Lj6xZMuteBwx3TWlslmlqow8E1HFn0Wp7+4o1pX7WH2+rl4q3PqeMJAkWbgJ8GkNKmqHMEaUI7E5HD0hrqMfMui8M7BztPWpOHEJtr50mvo2XsKMmNnHke+5exHFwi3gYKaTv0keognSc6WJzmIprF+grubOetfm/Lo5k1t3xRpXbffHDSh/BPq6iNfj4T/IjqubDMeNWtVIephP6j+Tx0uk/S0AgAA)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that match the data structure in your scenario.

* It is the same solution is the other solution I just modified, but since the source data structure is different, I posted an additional answer for learning purposes.

The original data looks something like that:

[image: Data]

The code is actually very simple, leveraging [column_ifexists()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/columnifexists):

```
// Data sample generation. Not part of the solution.
let p_start_time = startofday(ago(1d));
let p_interval = 5m;
let p_rows = 15;
let p_cols = 120;
let data = materialize
(
    range Timestamp from p_start_time to p_start_time + p_rows * p_interval step p_interval
    | mv-expand MetricID = range(1, p_cols) to typeof(int)
    | extend MetricVal = rand(), MetricName = strcat("x", tostring(MetricID))
    | evaluate pivot(MetricName, take_any(MetricVal), Timestamp)
    | project-reorder Timestamp, * granny-asc 
 );
// Solution starts here
// We assume the creation of a parameter named _MetricName, in the dashboard
// Uncomment the following line when executed outside the context of the dashboard
let ['_MetricName'] = "x42"; 
data
| project Timestamp, column_ifexists(['_MetricName'], real(null))
| render timechart
```

| Timestamp | x42 |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-10-13T00:00:00Z | 0.89472385054721115 |
| 2022-10-13T00:05:00Z | 0.11275174098360444 |
| 2022-10-13T00:10:00Z | 0.96233152692333268 |
| 2022-10-13T00:15:00Z | 0.21751913633816042 |
| 2022-10-13T00:20:00Z | 0.69591667527850931 |
| 2022-10-13T00:25:00Z | 0.36802228024058203 |
| 2022-10-13T00:30:00Z | 0.29060518653083045 |
| 2022-10-13T00:35:00Z | 0.13362332423562559 |
| 2022-10-13T00:40:00Z | 0.013920161307282448 |
| 2022-10-13T00:45:00Z | 0.05909880950497 |
| 2022-10-13T00:50:00Z | 0.146454957813311 |
| 2022-10-13T00:55:00Z | 0.318823204227693 |
| 2022-10-13T01:00:00Z | 0.020087435985750794 |
| 2022-10-13T01:05:00Z | 0.31110660126024159 |
| 2022-10-13T01:10:00Z | 0.75531136771424379 |
| 2022-10-13T01:15:00Z | 0.99289833682620265 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=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)

[image: Dashboard]

Comment: Ah, wonderful. column_ifexists never came up when I was looking for an answer.
Is there a way to get it to work with multiselect parameters?

Comment: Yes. see new answer.